# How do rockets prevent rear-ending after stage seperation?

Tags: rockets, stages

On the third flight of SpaceX's Falcon 1, the following failure occurred [according to one narrative](http://www.slate.com/blogs/quora/2013/08/14/elon_musk_what_is_it_like_to_work_for_the_spacex_tesla_chief.html).

> We turned off the first-stage engine and then proceeded to separate the vehicle stages; however, when the stages uncoupled, there was still a little leftover "kick," or thrust, in the first-stage engine. Our first stage literally rear-ended our second stage immediately after we had tried to separate the two sections of the vehicle. It was a devastating, emotional experience.

Sounds logical.  You wouldn't want to wait until your prior stage fully putters out completely before separating because (among other things) you'll lose altitude.  Ideally, you'd want to be delivering as much thrust as possible as constantly as possible, and that might entail having some kick left in the prior stage.

In the general sense (not specific to SpaceX), how is this avoided in vertically staged rockets?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This type of failure is known as separation failure which is caused due to timing error in separating the stages

> Musk said SpaceX would be releasing video of the staging event that clearly shows that the first and second stages separated as planned about 2 minutes and 20 seconds into the flight, but that unanticipated residual thrust from the redesigned Merlin engine caused the first stage to bump the second stage just as it began to fire

This is normally overcome in the rockets by

- shutting down the rocket engine properly (cutting down the fuel source(liquid propellent)  in case of [solid propellent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid-fuel_rocket) it is  impossible to shut down so timing is very important the fuel is entirely burnt before shut down)

[Source](http://www.cctv.com/program/Nature&Science/20050531/101773.shtml):

> The separation of large boosters uses direct staging. Each booster is connected to the rocket’s core through a bar mechanism in the front joint side and the round head mechanism in the back joint side. When the engine of the booster stops working, the connection bolt and separation nut will be unlocked separately. The small separation rockets that are bound to the boosters are ignited and separate the boosters from the core. The boosters fall down and separation is complete.

Comment: Also, if you engage the second stage engine fast enough, it will simply push the other stage off-course.

Comment: If the first stage still have fuel it could accelerate since the second stage is still yet to kick start(small time difference in igniting second stage )

Comment: If the first stage still keeps thrust then the stages won't separate as the first stage still pushes against the second. Only in case of a hiccup, when the first stage pretty much cuts off, and then reignites after separation this would be possible - or in case the disengaging system pushes them apart briefly but doesn't provide continuous thrust.

Comment: For the record, Solid Propellent isn't impossible to shut down, one simply has to eject the fuel, which is actually fairly commonly and easily done.

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto: Have not heard of ejecting solid propellant.  Can you please explain further?

Comment: @JS.: See my answer at http://space.stackexchange.com/a/10250/25

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto: That patent appears to cover a solid rocket/scramjet hybrid.  I can see how ejecting the nozzle constriction would *lower* thrust.  Is that equivalent to ejecting the solid fuel?  I'm curious to see the mechanism used to safely eject (burning) solid-rocket fuel.

Comment: I wish I knew more about it. I only know that it can happen for sure, I don't really know the details as to how it works, aside from ejecting the fuel somehow. I think the whole rocket is in some high pressure, which is controlled. If you release the fuel, it will blow out of the rocket unspent, which can be accomplished by blowing a hole in the right spot in a solid fuel rocket.

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto Solid propellent typically only burns while a certain combustion pressure is maintained. Hence, while solid propellent motors cannot be actively throttled, they can be "shut off" by venting adequate pressure ([even violently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_safety#Launch_corridor)) from the combustion chamber.

Comment: When they separate they have the same speed. And then how is the distance between them increasing before the second stage engine is started? What is pushing the first stage away from the second stage?